# knockout.js can I pass an an array of data to a template?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Working with Knockout templates, all of the examples seem to pass in single values to the template instead of array data. I have a template which will create some basic HTML, and then render a table using the data passed in to the template. Here is how it looks:

```
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
    <p>Here is the data</p>
    [MORE HTML DATA HERE]

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: [WHAT DO I PUT HERE???]">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Surname"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>


<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: PersonArray1 }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: PersonArray2 }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: PersonArray3 }"></div>
```

The templates do support a foreach binding, but I don't think I can use that as I don't want the template HTML heading data marked [MORE HTML DATA HERE] repeated for every item in the array.

I want the foreach binding within the template as in my rough example above. Is there a way I can make this work? I think the answer is in the placeholder i have marked with [WHAT DO I PUT HERE???] above, but I don't know if there is a variable which holds top-level template data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from this link, and the solution was posted by the creator himself.

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/246

The solution is supplied in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/b9WWF/

The part of interest is where you call your template, instead of supplying an object directly to the data attribute, you can supply data in named values as follows:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: { people: PersonArray1 } }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: { people: PersonArray2, displayAdmins: false } }"></div>
```

You then access the array in your template as follows (I'm using my code above as an example):

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [`$data`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) parameter which will give you each entry from the supplied array:

```js
var myViewModel = {
    PersonArray1 : [
      { Id: 1, FirstName: "Alice", Surname: "Bloggs" },
      { Id: 2, FirstName: "Bob", Surname: "Bloggs" },
      { Id: 3, FirstName: "Claire", Surname: "Bloggs" }
    ]
};

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
    <p>Here is the data</p>
    [MORE HTML DATA HERE]

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Surname"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>


<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: PersonArray1 }"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much - $data certainly works, but see below for an even tidier solution which I found whilst Googling. It seems even more robust. It's a shame it's not part of the documentation actually as it's REALLY useful - especially since it effectively allows multiple parameters.